# Was Nick sent to jail for shooting his friend?

Tags: csi-new-york

In the [*CSI: NY*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0395843/) episode "Battle Scars", Nick confesses he shot his friend (Jesse), but it was an accident and it was Jesse who planned all  of this. In the end they believe he was telling the truth but we never know the outcome of Nick. Did he go to jail?

Comment: I haven't seen the episode but most likely its not revealed because its not pertinent to the plot. We can assume that his case was sent to the attorney general and they either pressed charges or came up with some sort of plea deal.